# thread doesn't execute run method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm having problems with threads ... I think the jframe one with the serial one is in conflict
I would need a thread to always read and write from the serial, while the other to refresh the jframe

The problem is this thread never... NewThread not executing the code in run (), but i dont' understand when is the problem

if i run this program the jframe work but "newthread" causes an error to appear in the console.
This is the log of the console:

```
compile:
run:
Child thread: Thread[Demo Thread,5,main]
Exception in thread "Demo Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at NewThread.run(JFrameAcquario.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

This is the class for the serial communication

```
class NewThread extends thread  {
 SerialPort serialPort; 
 String[] listPort; 
 Thread t;
   NewThread() {
      
      t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
      System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
      t.start(); 
   }
public  void run (String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    int a;
    int A[]={2,9,4,7,3,6};
    int B[]={0,0,0,0};
    SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3"); // device name TODO: must be changed
    sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0); // default connection settings for Arduino
    sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0); // block until bytes can be written
    
    if (sp.openPort()) {
      System.out.println("Port is open :)");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Failed to open port :(");
      return;
    }        
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {            
      sp.getOutputStream().write(A[i]);
      sp.getOutputStream().flush();
      
     
            
      System.out.println("Sent number: " + A[i]);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
   
    
    

    if(sp.getInputStream() != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
         a = sp.getInputStream().read();
         B[i]=a;
         System.out.println("Recived number: " + B[i]);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
    }    
        
        }
    
    if (sp.closePort()) {
      System.out.println("Port is closed :)");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Failed to close port :(");
      return;
    }
    
  }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

This is the class jframe

```
public class JFrameAcquario extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    boolean init = false;
    int send[];
    Timer timer;
    
    
    public JFrameAcquario(String args){
        
        initComponents();
        
        ActionListener actionLisatener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Date date = new Date();
                DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
                String time = timeFormat.format(date);
                ORA_ESATTA.setText(time);
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer(1000, actionLisatener);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
        
        TEMP_MIS.setText(Integer.toString(co2));
        TEMP_MIS.repaint();
        TEMP_MIS.update(TEMP_MIS.getGraphics());
        
    }
```

This is the main

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new NewThread();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrameAcquario(null).setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? ... please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In order to do anything that changes the gui (such as changing text), you must create a third thread and run this with InvokeLater().

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker`. This class creates a background Thread and allows you to either periodically "publish" results to update the GUI or you can update the GUI when the Thread finishes executing, or both. Read the Section from the Swing tutorial on [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: I edit the post with more information e more code